# Cast contiguous block of memory into higher-dimensional array for ease of indexing

Tags: c

I have a function that gets passed a linear block of memory that encodes a row-major stored higher-dimensional matrix (3d, 4d, ...).

Is there a way to cast the memory such that efficient multidimensional indexing is possible?

```
void do_something_in_4d(float* input, int dim1, int dim2, int dim3, int dim4) {
    // input_4d = (some casting magic) input

    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    int m = 3;
    int n = 4;

    // input_4d[i][j][m][n] == input[i*dim2*dim3*dim4 + j*dim3*dim4 + m*dim4 + n]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use C99 variable length arrays for this. Note that in case you ever need compatibility, these are not supported by any C++ version so far, and compilers like MSVC (as of 2019) don't implement them.

Now while the commonly seen form is the ability to do something like `int arr[n]` or `int arr[w][h]` as a stack variable, it does in fact work for pointers as well.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void matrix_print(int x, int y, int z, int w, float (*matrix_4d)[y][z][w]);
void matrix_set(int x, int y, int z, int w, float (*matrix_4d)[y][z][w]);
int main()
{

    int width = 3;
    float matrix2[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    float (*matrix_2d)[width] = (float(*)[width])matrix2;
    printf("%f\n", matrix_2d[0][0]); // 0
    printf("%f\n", matrix_2d[0][1]); // 1
    printf("%f\n", matrix_2d[0][2]); // 2
    printf("%f\n", matrix_2d[1][0]); // 3
    printf("%f\n", matrix_2d[1][1]); // 4
    printf("%f\n", matrix_2d[1][2]); // 5

    int x=2,y=3,z=4,w=5;
    float *matrix4 = malloc(sizeof(float)*x*y*z*w);

    float (*matrix_4d)[y][z][w] = (float (*)[y][z][w]) matrix4;
    matrix_set(x, y, z, w, matrix_4d);
    printf("1D matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x*y*z*w; ++i)
        printf("%f\n", matrix4[i]); // 0 to 119
    matrix_print(x, y, z, w, matrix_4d);
}
void matrix_set(int x, int y, int z, int w, float (*matrix_4d)[y][z][w])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int xi = 0; xi < x; ++xi)
        for (int yi = 0; yi < y; ++yi)
            for (int zi = 0; zi < z; ++zi)
                for (int wi = 0; wi < w; ++wi, ++i)
                    matrix_4d[xi][yi][zi][wi] = i;
}
void matrix_print(int x, int y, int z, int w, float (*matrix_4d)[y][z][w])
{
    printf("4D\n");
    printf("%f\n", matrix_4d[0][0][0][0]); // 0
    printf("%f\n", matrix_4d[0][0][0][1]); // 1
    printf("%f\n", matrix_4d[0][0][1][0]); // 5
    printf("%f\n", matrix_4d[0][1][0][0]); // 20
    printf("%f\n", matrix_4d[1][0][0][0]); // 24
    printf("%f\n", matrix_4d[1][2][3][4]); // 119
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the `input` pointer to a 3-D variable-length array pointer type and access it like a 4-D array:

```
float (*input_4d)[dim2][dim3][dim4] = (float (*)[dim2][dim3][dim4])input;
```

For readability, I'd introduce a `typedef` for the 3-D array:

```
typedef float f3d[dim2][dim3][dim4];
f3d *input_4d = (f3d *)input;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming C99 compatibility, then yes, you can cast the array as a multi dimensional VLA.

```
float (*input_4d)[dim2][dim3][dim4] = (float(*)[dim2][dim3][dim4])input;
```